# Operand Types Are Not Compatible With The Operator

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I am receiving the error

> Operand Types Are Not Compatible With The Operator

in the title when trying to compare two "real" datatypes.

Can anyone help me out with what is wrong?

```
public void clicked()
{
    real    localAnnualUsage    = itemSetup_DS.AnnualUsage();
    real    localSalesPrice     = itemSetup.StockPrice;
    real    localCost           = itemSetup.StockCost;
    real    localstockInventAvg = itemSetup.StockInventAvg;

    real    localTurnAndEarn;
    real    localAnnualGP;
    real    localAvgInvCost;
    ;

    localAvgInvCost = itemSetup.StockInventAvg;

    if (localStockInventAvg != itemSetup_StockInventAvg)
    {
        localAvgInvCost = itemSetup_StockInventAvg;
    }

    //...
}
```

The error happens with on the line of the conditional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your `itemSetup_StockInventAvg` variable is a real *control*, not a real.

Try using:

```
if (localStockInventAvg != itemSetup_StockInventAvg.realValue())
```

or better (because the control stores the result in `itemSetup.StockInventAvg`):

```
if (localStockInventAvg != itemSetup.StockInventAvg)
```

Update: This makes no sense, since `localStockInventAvg` was set to `itemSetup.StockInventAvg` the line before.